# Starting a WM on login with a macOS

Tags: window-manager, macos

I'm new to Apple/macOS and come from Linux where if I wanted to start a different WM I would just drop into a terminal and change my `.xinitrc`, or change the config for the display manager. I'd like to switch to `yabai`, but it seems odd to me to have to run a script to launch it and kill the things that I don't need.

What's the typical process for this?

Comment: Have your read the installation instruction given [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai)?  There is no typical process for running a window manager other than Apple's Finder on macOS as most users typically use the pre-existing WM.